# When Linux Kernel Source moved filesystem headers?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, linux-kernel

Does anyone know the last version of the kernel before the `fs` headers was moved <del>to the root</del>? <del>I think it used to be `/sys/fs/`.</del>

My memory (from 2010-ish) is less vague than a google search (nothing), it was something like 2.4.26 or 2.6.24 (or 2.6.18).

[EDIT #1]

If Stephens answer is correct, then that is the kernel headers only, not the drivers themselves. There used to be 2 seperate filesystem related forlders in the source. The refactor may have consolidated them.

I know for a fact that they were moved, because I was looking at adding `ext3fs/ext4fs/reiserfs` to FreeMiNT around 2010, and I found that its `ext2fs` structure was *identical* to the linux sources, up to a certain version, consisting of only modified linux source files, meaning that any new drivers could be uplift with filesystem structure intact, and placed into FreeMiNT source tree and they would be in the correct place to start both modification, and compilation

[EDIT #2]

So it appears the "move" I was refering to was in fact the filesystem headers, *not* the drivers, but also that the files within the drivers changed (title changed to reflect this). So in what version did those changes happen.

Comment: part of my confusin in the OP stems from the fact I cant find any servers that I can use to do a comparison, like I did in 2010-ish.

Comment: Do you remember what kind of changes you have in mind regarding the files *within* the drivers? (One would expect them to change anyway, as features are added, or as drivers are replaced, as happened with the Ext3 driver a few years ago.)

Comment: it was significant, like there names, as opposed to their content (except "probably" the header links). there was a post I found at the time noting the reasons for the changes, which I also cant find, I think they streamlined ALL the filesystem drivers. it may have been only one file name. do you have any links on a browseable repo server, I cant find anything with google, just http/ftp source package servers

Comment: I tend to use [Elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/), which goes back to 2.6.12 (when Linus’ current git tree was created). There are various git repos with older commits, I’ll dig them up tomorrow.

Comment: thanks, it may have been 2.6.18 - I see if I can check/compare - nope not that ..

Comment: I have `/fs/ext2fs/ext2sys.c` and `/fs/ext2fs/ext2dev.c`, not found in 2.6.18, and no `acl.c` - I think it maybe 2.4.26 then

Comment: those 1st 2 files mentioned above maybe FreeMiNT specific. here is 2.4.22 without `acl.c`, and all the `xattr` files (and no internal header files): http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/fs/ext2/?v=linux-2.4.22

Comment: hmm, "acl" there is a "dont-use" 2.4.11 that has it, but there is this on the wiki: ```Most of the Unix and Unix-like operating systems (e.g. Linux since 2.5.46 or November 2002,[7] BSD, or Solaris) support POSIX.1e ACLs (not necessarily draft 17).``` so when were the headers rearranged?

Comment: `2.4.37` does not contain `ext2.h` , but `2.5.45` does, and so does the FreeMiNT source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technically correct answer to the OP is "they" were never *moved* (same goes for the *drivers* in the original title, not just the *headers*).

However, specifically regarding the `ext2` filesystem driver, `ext2.h` was *created* as of Linux Kernel 2.5.3, while the 2nd folder refered to was actually the standard header `include` folder (where the headers were revised and/or refactored). Finally, the "filename changes" mentioned were due to the final inclusion of ACL (Access Control List) and the XATTR (eXtended ATTRibutes) files which were introduced in 2.5.46, while the `sys/fs/` reference was actually `sys/xfs/` from the FreeMiNT source tree.

```
2.5.3  - uploaded 30-Jan-2002 19:19
2.5.45 - uploaded 31-Oct-2002 00:51
2.5.46 - uploaded 04-Nov-2002 22:51
```

The reason for the additon of `fs/ext2/ext2.h` can be found in a comment in that file:

> Ok, these declarations are also in `<linux/kernel.h>` but none of the ext2 source programs needs to include it so they are duplicated here.

The result of this question has proved (to me at least) how useless Google has become for this sort of research, and how much of the "internet" (specifically the web) has disappeared or been restructured to detrimental effect. If it were not for Stephens answer and subsequent comments and that link, I would not have been able to get this far (there needs to be better/alternate credit systems on StackExchange). Thank god for FTP servers and the massive size of removeable media.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, have an upvote (not just to balance things out, you’re answering your own question in a useful way). You’re welcome ;-). (Feel free to accept your own answer BTW.)

Comment: K, ta, thnx again :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your memory is playing tricks on you: the file system code has been in `/fs` in the Linux kernel source ever since [version 0.01](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/linux-0.01.tar.gz).

Comment: exactly my point, I know you are wrong, there are "loose" references to `/sys/fs/` on google (not including `/proc/sys/fs/`), but I can not find the servers I used to do the comaparision back in 2010-ish. The source filesystem was refactored for version 3, and the repo was moved to github in 2011

Comment: Are you talking about the location of the file system source code within the kernel source code, or about something else?

Comment: "kernel source code" see my edit

Comment: OK, so I did understand your question correctly. Feel free to prove me wrong, all the old kernel source trees are still around. The `/fs` directory has always contained the driver source code, the headers live elsewhere (and *they* were restructured, which might be what you’re remembering).

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, but I also know that the files within the driver folders were change, as I was able to verify that against the `ext2` files found in FreeMiNT. I'm just looking for the kernel version where that changed (the one before actually).

Comment: There has *never* been a top level directory called `sys` containing file system code in the Linux kernel source tree. Not in Linus's "official" tree, anyway. Googling for `/sys/fs` gives a lot of hits, because a running Linux machine has `/sys/fs`, but it has nothing to do with source code.

Comment: yeah I realise that, the closest I found so far refered to NetBSD. Note that at the time (in 2010-ish) I made a post to a mailing list regarding the correct Linux source version to use as a reference, which I am as yet (also) unable to find.

Comment: Looking into it some more, AFAICT the header restructuring didn’t affect the file system headers, so my earlier comment is incorrect in that regard. Most file system headers live inside the respective file system source directories (*e.g.* `fs/ext2/ext2.h`), a few are shared but haven’t moved (`include/linux/vfs.h`, `include/linux/ext2_fs.h` etc.).